# How to download file by clicking on icon in file module?

Tags: 7, files

I have a File field in drupal 7 (with file module) which I forced with views to display as an icon and name of the file which uploaded. The Name displays as a link (to download file). Now I want to link the icon to the file too. So when users click on the icon they would be available to download file (and I prefer to exclude the name from display).
What should I do now to make the icon as a download link?
Thanks.

Comment: how did you "force" views to display the icon?

Comment: actually I didn't force views, sorry. I set Display Field Format to: File Force: Generic file, and it prints an icon with a link text!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that 'html' in $options is set to FALSE by default, thus stripping the icon html code generated by theme().

I tried modifying a bit the code above and it worked perfectly:

```
/**
 * Implements theme_file_link().
 */
function yourtheme_file_link($variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
  $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' =>     $icon_directory));

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  // http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples
  $options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
    ),
  );

  // Updating 'html' to TRUE so that the html code to display the icon is     printed
  $options += array(
    'html' => TRUE,
  );


  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file->description)) {
    $link_text = $file->filename;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file->description;
    $options['attributes']['title'] = check_plain($file->filename);
  }

  return '<span class="file">' . l($icon, $url, $options) . ' ' .     l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

Note that I added 3 lines (plus a commented line, 4) to update the value of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements theme_file_link().
 */
function yourtheme_file_link($variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
  $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  // http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples
  $options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
    ),
  );

  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file->description)) {
    $link_text = $file->filename;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file->description;
    $options['attributes']['title'] = check_plain($file->filename);
  }

  return '<span class="file">' . l($icon, $url, $options) . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: place it in your active theme's template.php then clear the cache, refresh.

Comment: it doesn't work for me:( I've found similar code in file.module file (of course instead of two lines,last one and 8th). shouldn't I change that file too?  And I have change `yourtheme` to `bartik` which is my default template. Your code seems to be worked, but there should be a problem, can you define it?

Comment: No. You should never mod any core file including the file.module.  What I post is implementation of theme_file_link, which overrides the default theme_file_link defined in file.module.